# Check if file opened bash

Tags: bash

Hey I'm trying to write a bash script and have a question. What is the best way to check if a specific file is not opened and done being written. I need to do this inside an if statement?

Pseudocode:

```
If abc.txt not opened
  Do this
Else
  Do this
```

Comment: Even if bash offered a way to do this, the information would be obsolete the moment the check is completed, as another process can open or close a file at any time.

Comment: It's not obsolete at all.   If a large file is being written I need to make sure it's done before I attempt to process it.

Comment: In general, if the check returns false, meaning the file is not open, another process could, at that very moment, open the file and append more data. Thus, the result of the check, indicating that the file is not open, would no longer be correct. The information would be obsolete.

Comment: If you are waiting for some other process to complete, there are methods to do that. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: My process is the only one that will touch the file.   But I need to know if the file is complete before I proceed it.

Comment: If your process is the only one touching the file, then you would know whether or not the file is opened by your process from information inside your process. Do you mean inside your bash script, which executes some command which writes to the file?

Comment: I'm trying to check if the file is done being written before I attempt to process it.   If it's in the process of being written I need to skip and check the next one in the list.

Comment: You said only your process touches the file; how do you *not* know if you are done writing to it or not?

Comment: (a) Is your bash script writing to the file **directly** — not via a command or other subprocess? (b) Does your bash script execute a command (run a program, spawn any process) that writes to the file? (c) You wrote that “your process” is the only one touching the file. Is that “your process” the bash script or something else? (d) Is that “your process” a program you wrote, some utility, or what?

Comment: No I won't know because it's being copied to a folder from a different source.   Once it's complete mine is the only process to touch it.

Comment: The standard way to fix this is to have the writer write to a temporary file first, and when it has finished, rename the temporary file to the "real" file in one atomic step. The real file only appears after all the data that's going to be written to has been written.

Comment: So there are two processes that touch the file—one is the process that is copying, and another is “mine” (the bash script?). Please do not write that your process is the only one touching the file when there are two processes involved. You need to give people a complete picture of what is involved.

Comment: So, we have two processes, at least. One is the process that copies files. Another is your bash script. Yes? When the files are being copied, does one process copy all the files, or is there a separate process for each file being copied? What process is this—is it a standard copy/archive/synchronize command? Is it started by your bash script?

Comment: I'm failing to see how that's relevant.   I just want to check if the file is in the process of being written.   How can I do that.

Comment: The bash shell does not offer any built-in way to determine whether a file is open or not. (There is a system-dependent way to do this, but it is privileged and not suitable for use in routine shell scripts.) The questions are relevant because I sought an alternative way to accomplish your ultimate goals. If you do not wish to provide information, then I cannot help you.

Comment: I don't know what process it is,  and the customer won't provide this info.  My script is just calling some standard libraries to operate on the files but they must be fully written to disk.

Comment: You can give a look to lsof(8), may be it helps.

Comment: @linuxfan: I was thinking of `lsof`, but it is a CPU hog and was not intended for this use. Using it in a loop to wait for file copies to complete would be horribly inefficient. If somebody does try it, they should ensure the paths it displays are reconciled with the paths they are attempting to monitor (symbolic links are resolved, expansions for `~` or shell variables are performed, et cetera). It can be targeted at a specific process or processes.

Comment: Yea I was looking at lsof, but it's not quite what I need.

Comment: Perhaps a better option is to use  inotifywait.

Comment: Yes, you could do that, waiting for the `close_write` event.

Comment: But it would be better to work with the cient to implement the method @chepner described. It's failsafe because if the writing process crashes, it won't do the rename at the end, and you'll then ignore the file it was writing.

Comment: If you know the process that is writing the job you might be able to watch for it to exit, but that doesn't guarantee success. Your paradigm is broken. They should write to a temp and then rename so that if the file exists it's complete. If that is not an option (and it likely is if you push back hard enough), then have them write a flag file *separately* once the main file is done, though that opens up another set of nightmares... What you have to do, though, is stop assuming the way you thought of to do it is the only way, or even an ok way. It isn't.

Comment: Even a `close_write` doesn't guarantee the write is complete; the client might open it again and append some data. There is no technical solution to this without cooperation from the writer, in the form of a non-ambiguous signal that indicates it is safe to treat the file as complete. (That signal could be a `close_write` event, if the client promises that once they close a file, they won't open it again.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With lsof command you can get the files that are currently open.

```
$> lsof | grep abc.txt | wc -l
```

If that is not 0, the file is open.
If you know the pid of the process that should be using that file, you could use it to filter the results using -p option.

```
$> lsof -p <pid>
```

Comment: The sample code shown falsely reports `abc.txt` is open when it is not but `qabc3.txt` is open, for example. Also, there is no need for `wc`; `grep -q` will silence output and report results in its exit status.

Comment: `lsof abc.txt` should be sufficient to list the processes that have opened `abc.txt`, instead of grepping the list of all open files.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to check if a file is done being written is have the writer signal that it is done. This signal can take many forms, but a common one is to only create the expected file name once all writing is complete. This is accomplished by writing to a *temporary* file, and only renaming it after the write as complete successfully:

```
cp foo bar.tmp && mv bar.tmp bar
some_long_process > bar.tmp && mv bar.tmp bar
```

Now you, as the consumer, can be assured that if `bar` exists *at all*, it is complete and ready to be used.

```
# Polling only used as an example; operating-system-specific
# solutions that block until notification of the file's creation
# are vastly preferred
while [ ! -e bar ]; do
    echo "Bar doesn't exist yet..."
    sleep 1
done

echo "Bar exists!"
do_something_with bar
```